# Xamarin ContentPage.ToolbarItems move to the bottom of page

Tags: xamarin.forms

The following is my code what I want to do is move the toolbar to the bottom of the page after the grid

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Icon="heart.png" Command="{Binding GotoWishlistCommand}"/>
    <ToolbarItem Icon="shoppingcart.png"
                 Command="{Binding GotoCartCommand}"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converter:SelectedToColorConverter x:Key="cnvInvert"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Comment: please add some examples of what you do. Currently is a totally understandable question.

Comment: I do not think what you want is possible with Xamarin Forms. Toolbar items are placed at the top of the page as default.

Comment: Maybe you can custom a view like ToolbarItem .You can customize an empty view, which adds two buttons.

Comment: Hi, have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `ToolbarItem` is designed by default at the top of the page.

If want to move `ToolbarItem` to bottom of the page,this can be done by custom view.You can create a `StackLayout` , and it contains buttons like ToolbarItem in it.In addition,StackLayout can be setted below `GridLayout`.Then this seems like as a `ToolbarItem` on the bottom of the page.

Example Code as follow:

```
<StackLayout>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Text="Top Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
            <Label Text="Top Right" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
            <Label Text="Bottom Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
            <Label Text="Bottom Right" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>

        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="BlueViolet" x:Name="CustomToolBarItem" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" WidthRequest="1000">
            <ImageButton Source="heart.png" Command="{Binding GotoWishlistCommand}" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            <ImageButton Source="shoppingcart.png" Command="{Binding GotoCartCommand}" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add in the TabbedPage this lines if you are trying to put in the bottom for android. For iOS it's as default.

```
xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
```

Finally, your page will be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage
  x:Class="SampleApp.MainPage"
  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
  xmlns:views="clr-namespace:SampleApp"
  android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom">
  <TabbedPage.Children>
    <NavigationPage
      Title="Browse"
      BackgroundColor="White"
      Icon="tab_feed.png">
      <x:Arguments>
        <views:ItemsPage />
      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
    <NavigationPage
      Title="About"
      BackgroundColor="White"
      Icon="tab_about.png">
      <x:Arguments>
        <views:AboutPage />
      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```